# jshint - Don't make functions within a loop using Array.find

Tags: javascript, jshint

I know this question has been around for a while, but I haven't found an answer that could solve my case (sorry if I missed any).

Anyway, I have the following code:

```
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    let value = array[i];
    let anotherValue = anotherArray.find(val => val.key === value.key);
}
```

That code makes jshint to throw the warning: *Don't make functions within a loop. (W083)*

The fact that I need access to a variable that's within the "for" scope gives me the need of having a function declared inside it.

I have tried the following approach:

```
let myFunc = (val) => {
    //no value here to compare
}
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    let value = array[i];
    let anotherValue = anotherArray.find(myFunc);
}
```

If I declare it outside the *for* I can't access the **value** variable.

Comment: Just turn off that warning message.

Comment: The problem isn't the message at all. That would be easy to get rid of. I just think that it has to be a better implementation.

Comment: Your implementation is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Array.forEach` instead of a `for`-loop:

```
array.forEach((value) => {
  let anotherValue = anotherArray.find(val => val.key === value.key);
  /* do anything with anotherValue */
}
```

Alternatively, you can [curry your function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) in order to be able to take `value` and still have a function:

```
let myFunc = candidate => target => candidate.key === target.key;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let anotherValue = anotherArray.find(myFunc(array[i]));
}
```

And yet alternatively, you can tell JSHint to ignore this rule in this file by adding a directive to the top of your file:

```
/* jshint loopfunc: true */
```

Comment: The curry approach also generates a function on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: It does, I just don't think jshint would complain about it since the "function generator" is defined outside of the loop. I haven't tested this, though.